# Canonical Markov Chain

Tags: probability

I am currently studying the canonical Markov chain and, with that, the Markov property (with expectation).

However, I don't understand a point.

Indeed, if we give ourself a probability $\mu$ with a transition matrix $P$. So the canoncical Markov chain come to be $(\Omega,\sigma(X_k, k \geq 0), \sigma(X_k, k \leq n), (X_n)_{n \geq 0}, (\mathbf{P}_x)_{x \in E}) $ with<sup>[src)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEDGc.png)</sup>

\begin{gather*}
\Omega = E^N, \qquad \omega = (\omega_n)_{n\geq 0}, \qquad X_n(\omega) = \omega_n, \\
\mathscr{F}_n = \sigma(X_k : k \leq n), \qquad \mathscr{F} = \sigma(X_k : k \geq 0).
\end{gather*}

Moreover,<sup>[src)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y63fO.png)</sup>

$$ \mathbf{P}(X_0 = a_0, \ldots, X_n = a_n)
= \mu_n(a_0, \ldots, a_n)
= \mu(a_0) P(a_0, a_1) \ldots P(a_{n-1}, a_n) $$

is satisfied.

I don't reach to understand an important concept illustrated in this equality<sup>[src)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjoPD.png)</sup> (arrow)

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}_{\mu}(X_{n+1} = b_1, \ldots, X_{n+k} = b_k \mid \mathscr{F}_n)
&= P(X_n, b_1) \ldots P(b_{k-1}, b_k) \\
&\!\color{red}{\underset{\Huge\uparrow}{=}} \mathbf{P}_{X_n}(X_1 = b_1, \ldots, X_k = b_k).
\end{align*}

Indeed, my calcutation lead me to think that $\mathbf{P}(X_n=b_1)=P(X_n,b_1)$ :<sup>[src)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwvJj.png)</sup>

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}_{X_n}(X_1 = b_1, \ldots, X_k = b_k)
&= \sum_{x \in E} \mathbf{P}(X_n = x) \mathbf{P}_{x}(X_1 = b_1, \ldots, X_k = b_k) \\
&= \sum_{x \in E} \mathbf{P}(X_n = x) \delta_x(b_1)P(b_1, b_2) \ldots P(b_{k-1}, b_k) \\
&= \mathbf{P}(X_n = b_1) P(b_1, b_2) \ldots P(b_{k-1}, b_k)
\end{align*}

Thanks a lot for the consideration to this message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first line of your computation is not correct, because the left-hand side is a random variable whereas the right-hand side and thereafter are (deterministic) numbers.

In order to prove the highlighted step, recall the following definition: For an integrable r.v. $Y$, the conditional expectation $\mathbf{E}_{\mu}[Y \mid \mathscr{F}_n]$ is an $\mathscr{F}_n$-measurable r.v. such that

$$ \mathbf{E}_{\mu}[\mathbf{E}_{\mu}[Y \mid \mathscr{F}_n] \mathbf{1}_{A}] = \mathbf{E}_{\mu}[Y \mathbf{1}_{A}] $$

for every $A \in \mathscr{F}_n$. Now, since $\mathscr{F}_n$ is generated by $X_0, \ldots, X_n$, it suffices to test this when $A$ is of the form $A = \{X_0 = a_0, \ldots, X_n = a_n\}$ for each $(a_0, \ldots, a_n) \in E^{n+1}$. Indeed,

\begin{align*}
&\mathbf{E}_{\mu}[\mathbf{P}_{\mu}(X_{n+1} = b_1, \ldots, X_{n+k} = b_k \mid \mathscr{F}_n) \mathbf{1}_{A} ] \\
&= \mathbf{E}_{\mu}[\mathbf{1}_{\{X_{n+1} = b_1, \ldots, X_{n+k} = b_k\}} \mathbf{1}_{A} ] \\
&= \mathbf{P}_{\mu}(X_0 = a_0, \ldots, X_n = a_n, X_{n+1} = b_1, \ldots, X_{n+k} = b_k) \\
&= \mu(a_0)P(a_0, a_1) \cdots P(a_{n-1}, a_n) P(a_n, b_1) \cdots P(b_{k-1}, b_k) \\
&= \mu(a_0)P(a_0, a_1) \cdots P(a_{n-1}, a_n) \mathbf{P}_{a_n}(X_1 = b_1, \ldots, X_k = b_k) \\
&= \mathbf{E}_{\mu}[ \mathbf{P}_{X_n}(X_1 = b_1, \ldots, X_k = b_k) \mathbf{1}_{A} ].
\end{align*}

Since $\mathbf{P}_{X_n}(X_1 = b_1, \ldots, X_k = b_k)$ is an $\mathscr{F}_n$-measurable r.v., it follows that

$$ \mathbf{P}_{\mu}(X_{n+1} = b_1, \ldots, X_{n+k} = b_k \mid \mathscr{F}_n) = \mathbf{P}_{X_n}(X_1 = b_1, \ldots, X_k = b_k) $$

holds $\mathbf{P}_{\mu}$-a.s. by the uniqueness of the conditional expectation.